# I unloaded the default Solr Collection by mistake from the Solr Admin UI

Tags: solr, full-text-search, search-engine, lucene

How do I reload it into Solr again? If I try to launch the Solr Admin UI, I get the following message:

There are no SolrCores running. 
Using the Solr Admin UI currently requires at least one SolrCore.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will need to modify the `<cores>` entry in the solr.xml file that is in the root of where your Solr instance is running and add at least one `<core>` entry. Below is the example that comes with the Solr distribution.

```
      <cores adminPath="/admin/cores" defaultCoreName="collection1">
         <core name="collection1" instanceDir="." />
       </cores>
```

You will need to modify this according to your local settings. You can reference more information on Cores and their settings in the [CoreAdmin Solr Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin) page.

Comment: Stupid UI; it should warn you about stuff like that

Comment: The answer above stumped me for a while. If you do this, just re-add this line to the solr.xml file within the cores block. <core instanceDir="collection1" name="collection1"/>

Answer (score 0):

You can just run: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&core=collection1`
Please note that the path and port to your solr server are correct.